# Unable to redirect to a JSP file from servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have been trying to redirect my home page to a JSP file, but I am having some trouble. When I redirect the page from the servlet to my `index.jsp` page, I am receiving a `404 error`. I have tried with the following code:

```
resp.sendRedirect(req.getContextPath() + "/index.jsp");
resp.sendRedirect("/index.jsp");
resp.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
```

However, none of these have worked, so I would appreciate some help.

Comment: Could you post the directory path where your jsp is located.

Comment: I am using Eclipse, Maven Project (with web hirearchy). This is the pathj in my project : 
src/main/websapp/index.jsp

Comment: The folder must be webapp but I think is a typo, could you access from the browser to your jsp directly, could you check the log of the server to see if there is an error

Comment: I solved the problem by dropping the jsp file in the WebContent folder, Thank you very much for your help!